# Google Cloud Storage returns 404 even file is uploaded from GAE hosted application using BlobstoreService

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am facing a problem in GCS. In my application, I am trying to upload an image on GCS from application hosted on Google App Engine using BlobstoreService.generateUploadUrl() with appengine sdk 1.9.0.

I am generating the upload url using below code:

```
    public Status getUploadURL(@Named("uploadUrl") String uploadUrl, @Named("bucket") String bucket){
      BlobstoreService blobStoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
      UploadOptions uploadOptions = UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName(bucket);
      return new Status(blobStoreService.createUploadUrl(uploadUrl, uploadOptions));
    }
```

After getting the upload URL using the above code, I am setting this url in my upload form action:

```
    <form id="uploadForm" 
     action="https://vibhoretest.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6aV-O5cQ_eotQksnMP8NybW8Rei7ZYx2nQxpLN3Aph5-hnxriBHb2BRdfjYqusLER41UWvLp48KxaNiJJFwokpY-ClnmXZgNLuKgKvGgf4Cr-G-YomXmxJ_2055M-PUDmhnfuZOmw6BveexJHQh4oibwA5c5g/ALBNUaYAAAAAU4YMDlvwZRO4XLFDZbTwRrg9MuGI5ygJ/" 
     method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="key" value="${filename}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="success_action_status" value="201" />
      <input type="hidden" name="x-goog-acl" value="public-read" />
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
```

When, submitting this form getting the below error:

When I am submitting the form then image is getting uploaded and able to find in the bucket but also getting 404 in firefox firbug console as below:

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://vibhoretest.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6aV-O5cQ_eotQksnMP8NybW8Rei7ZYx2nQxpLN3Aph5-hnxriBHb2BRdfjYqusLER41UWvLp48KxaNiJJFwokpY-ClnmXZgNLuKgKvGgf4Cr-G-YomXmxJ_2055M-PUDmhnfuZOmw6BveexJHQh4oibwA5c5g/ALBNUaYAAAAAU4YMDlvwZRO4XLFDZbTwRrg9MuGI5ygJ/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCS forwards the request to your application when using signed URL, so make sure /upload url in your application is handled and is not throwing 404.

Comment: Thanks Ashish, It worked. I am surprised that /upload is hardcoded url. I was trying pass some custom parameters in callback url. I have tried /upload/#id  /upload?#id but didn't work. Finally /upload?id=#id worked for me with the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

How large is the file?  Make sure you set the Retry Parameters, to give adequate response time:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/retryparams_class

Also, is it taking 60 seconds to get the 404 response?

Comment: File size is of 1 KB. After submitting form it shows 404 error in 3-5 seconds. Probably I am missing some settings in Google App Engine or Cloud Storage.